# Swagger UI is not accessible

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, swagger-ui

I have a Spring Boot project which has following dependencies(Other dependencies are not shown here)

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Also I had WebSecurityConfig class as below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter()
    {
        return new JwtAuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure( AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder ) throws Exception
    {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService( userDetailsService )
                .passwordEncoder( passwordEncoder() );
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception
    {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {

        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception
    {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(  "/api/**" ).permitAll()
            .antMatchers( "/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources",
                    "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**",
                    "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui","/swagger-ui.html" ).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint( unauthorizedHandler ).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy( SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS ).and()
            .sessionManagement().maximumSessions( 100 )
            .sessionRegistry( sessionRegistry() );

        http.addFilterBefore( authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class );
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry()
    {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }
}
```

The WebMvcConfig is implemented as below.

```
@Component
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(final ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/**").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
        registry.addViewController("/UserManagement").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers( ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

The JwtAuthTokenFilter is given below

```
public class JwtAuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter
{

    @Autowired
    private JwtProvider tokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain )
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        try
        {

            String jwt = getJwt( request );
            if( jwt != null && tokenProvider.validateJwtToken( jwt ) )
            {
                String username = tokenProvider.getUserNameFromJwtToken( jwt );

                UserExtendedDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername( username );
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities() );
                authentication.setDetails( new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails( request ) );

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication( authentication );
            }
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            logger.error( "Can NOT set user authentication -> Message: {}", e );
        }

        filterChain.doFilter( request, response );
    }

    private String getJwt( HttpServletRequest request )
    {
        String authHeader = request.getHeader( "Authorization" );

        if( authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith( "Bearer " ) )
        {
            return authHeader.replace( "Bearer ", "" );
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

The http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs returns a response as below.

[image]

But when the url is entered as [enter link description here](http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html)

[image]

Below is the entry found from console.log

```
ERROR 14224 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.c.s.f.security.jwt.JwtAuthEntryPoint   : Unauthorized error. Message - Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

Your valuable input is mostly welcomed in order to solve this issue

Comment: Have you tried adding the addResourceHandlers() for swagger-ui
.... implements WebMvcConfigurer

Comment: Yes @Harsh Mishara , I have added. Will update the question

Comment: Show your `JwtAuthTokenFilter` implemention. Did you exclude these URLs in your implementation?

Comment: It;s included to the question, but urls were not excluded in that implementation

Comment: Does `/swagger-resources` works? Which endpoint it shows and contains `/swagger-ui.html`?

Comment: Could you share your solution?